# .net MVC Areas and subfolders

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using Areas in my project but I would like to organise my views within these areas into sub folders.

For example, I have an area called Members which contains a Controller called Settings and another Controller called MemberCategory. MemberCategory is in effect a subfolder of Settings.

I would like when I access the Member Category view for my url to resolve to Members/Settings/MemberCategory

At present it resolves to Members/MemberCategory

Is it possible to nest the views into subfolders and change the controller to point to

```
return View("Members/Settings/MemberCategory");
```

Or do this need to done with routing?

Any examples would be appreciated.

Comment: Um that should work, are you getting an error?

Comment: I am getting a 404 with the above.

Comment: Are you sure the source is coming from the views directory? Try ~ at the front.

Comment: Ok the view is now working, had to put the full address in ~/Members/Settings/MemberCategory/Index.cshtml However the url is still incorrect. How can I get the settings folder to appear in the url?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have resolved this problem with Routes and not nesting the views into subfolders.

In my Area Registration file I have added the following above the default route:

```
    context.MapRoute(
        "MemberCategory",
        "Members/Settings/MemberCategory",
        new { controller = "MemberCategory", action = "Index" }
    );

    context.MapRoute(
        "MemberCategoryAction",
        "Members/Settings/MemberCategory/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "MemberCategory", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Not sure if this is the most elegant way of doing this but it works in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like:

```
return this.View("../MailTemplates/ResetPassword");
```

To get to the view you want to use. The code editor will not be able to resolve this, but it works.

I think this is cleaner than:

```
return this.View("~/Areas/Cms/MailTemplates/ResetPassword");
```